# How to understand spark-submit script master is YARN?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

We have all 6 machine, hdfs and yarn service on all node, 1 master and 6 slaves.
And  we install Spark on 3 machine, 1 master, 3 workers ( 1 node  master + worker) . 
We know when `--master spark://[host]:[port]`, the job will run only 3 node use standalone mode.
And when use `spark-submit --master yarn` submit a jar, it's would use all 6 server cpu and memory or just use 3 spark worker node machine ? 
And if can run all 6 node, How left 3 server can know it's the Spark job?

Spark: 2.3.1
Hadoop: 2.7.3

Answer (score 0):

In yarn mode, spark-submit send resource allocation resource to yarn and the containers will be launched on different node managers based on resource availability.